# Drop/ Block Outgoing Emails in AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, blacklist

Is there a way to drop outgoing emails within SES?

This is because our email-service is temporarily sending emails to a dummy address in production and it's affecting our bounce-back rate negatively.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hacky but if you emove your verified sending domain or email it should stop the sends

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send to "dummy" addresses -- whether for simulating success or various failures -- you should be using the [SES Mailbox Simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html).  Messages to these targets do not affect your bounce rate or reputation, and do not count against your daily sending limit, but do count for purposes of your rolling send rate limit.

There is not a way to stop SES from trying to deliver messages you have asked it to deliver.